# hasPermissionTo always return TRUE in Spatie Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan

I'm calling via API with Bearer Token and the function `$myUser->hasPermissionTo('some permission')` always return true

When I execute `Auth::user()->getAllPermissions()`, it returns the correct permissions

```
[
    {
        "id": 49,
        "name": "edit articles",
        "guard_name": "api",
        "created_at": "2022-05-28T11:02:59.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-05-28T11:02:59.000000Z",
        "pivot": {
            "role_id": 10,
            "permission_id": 49
        }
    }
]
```

But when I execute `Auth::user()->hasPermissionTo('user_list');` it returns TRUE too. Any permission that I put in `hasPermissionsTo('any permission')`, returns TRUE

[image: Permissions table]

Comment: Did you find your problem solution?

Comment: Please if you found problem solution , put it because i have same problem